# jQuery : File Input Value needed?

Tags: jquery, file, upload

How could we get the file input full path using jquery ?

Comment: I think there's security reasons why it can't be done. If it could be done it would just be `$('#fileinput').val();`

Answer (score 2):

jQuery("input[type=file]").val(); just for the filename not the entire path.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Only filename can be read, not fullpath. This restriction is because of security.